# How to call parent activity function from ASyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, accountmanager

`setAccountAuthenticatorResult` can be called from the Activity, which extends `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`. My activity extends that, but launches ASyncTask and hence this `setAccountAuthenticatorResult` should be called from ASyncTask (or, the result of ASyncTask should be passed back to the main thread).

How to do it?

What is wrong in the code below?

```
AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bundle> task = new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this, consumer, provider, prefs).execute(uri);

public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bundle> {
    private Context context;

    public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
            OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bundle result) {
        context.setAccountAuthenticatorResult(); // doesn't work

    }
```

Comment: I've implemented the following: AsyncTask returns needed Bundle and I get its value with task.get() from the main thread. Is it correct approach?

Comment: Hi LA_ if possible please check my comment under Ollie's post. what do you think? cheers

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When you create the AsyncTask, you can add a new constructor to it, and pass in a reference to the Activity:

```
AsyncTask myTask = new MyTask(this);
```

And then from the onPostExecute() method in the AsyncTask you can call the method on the Activity.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    public MyActivity activity;

    public MyTask(MyActivity a)
    {
        this.activity = a;
    }

    //  ......

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        activity.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, @Ollie C. I've added my approach to the comments. Will it work in the same way as yours? Which approach is better?

Comment: I prefer to pass an activity reference rather than the other way around, as it makes more conceptual sense to me, and if I call the task to get the information, how will I know the task is in the right state? Btw, a third option that may be better for some scenarios (e.g. if you needed to update widgets and activities) would be to broadcast an intent, and use broadcast receivers to accept the message.

Comment: @Ollie C, in accordance with your approach, I've updated my question with the code - it doesn't work. What is wrong here?

Comment: setAccountAuthenticatorResult() is on the Activity class, not the Context class. Your "context" var is the wrong type, use the type of your Activity

Comment: In my code sample you'll see I am passing this, but note that this refers to the current activity, so the type of your AsyncTask constructor parameter needs to be Activity, or more specifically your subclass of it (e.g. MyActivity or whatever).

Comment: Yes, I got it. But it is not clear for me how to get the current activity to pass it as parameter.

Comment: In your activity, the current activity is referenced with this. So pass this to the AsyncTask when you create it. If the Activity class is called MyActivityClass (i.e. MyActivityClass extends Activity) then the type of the param on the constructor needs to be MyActivityClass, and the type of the activity var in the AsyncTask also needs to be like MyActivityClass.

Comment: Hi this is exactly what i am doing ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843389/which-is-better-design-regarding-asynctask-and-object-passing but i worry that calling back to the parent activity will then leave the object containing the Async task ie (MyTask) unable to be garbage collected. Am i completely wrong in that case? Any help really appreciated. Design wise is it generally better to simply keep async code contained with in the "parent" object and not have MyTask at all?

Comment: you should only use a weak reference to the activity so that it can be garbage collected.

Comment: What's wrong with using this?: MainActivity.this.someParam = whatever;

Comment: This will result in memory leaks, and if your app supports rotation possible null pointers.  Do not do this.  Instead, do MainActivity.this.someParam or create another subclass to pass between.

Comment: Why do you use `MyActivity`? Wouldn't `Activity` be correct?

Comment: @JoshPinter  `Activity` is correct, indeed. However if you happen to have your own custom Activity class that extends from `Activity`you can use that too. In this example `MyActivity` is a custom class extending from `Activity`

Comment: @NicolásCarrasco Right on. Thanks for clarifying. That makes sense. Just making sure I wasn't missing anything. ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Use Interface

Follow these steps:

**1) Create an interface**

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener{

   public void updateResult(String result);

}
```

**2) Use the listener in your AsyncTask**

```
DownloadSongTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

   private AsyncTaskListener listener;

   public DownloadSongTask(Context context)
   {
       listener= (AsyncTaskListener)context;    // Typecast 
   }

   @Override
   public void doInbackGround(String... params)
   {
       // Download code
       int downloadPerc = // calculate that
       publish(downloadPerc);   
   }

   @Override
   public void onPostExecute(String result)
   {
       listener.updateResult(String result);  // Use it 
   }

}
```

**3) Implement the interface in your Activity and Override the interface method**

```
  public class YourActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements AsyncTaskListener{

  // Activity code //
  new  DownloadSongTask(this).execute("Paradise.mp3");  // this is how you start Task

  public void yourMethod(String arg)
  {
    // Your method related Stuff
  }

  @Override 
  public void updateResult(String result){
        yourMethod(result);
  }

}
```

## Advantege of using interface?

This seems a lengthy approach at first but if you use this approach

> You can make a loosely coupled AsyncTask. Which means you can use same AsyncTask with any Activity in Future without even changing code in your AsyncTask.

## Relevant Links:

For better understanding you can read this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164128/cant-access-findviewbyid-in-asynctask/54360901#54360901)