# Android update FragmentManager after it loads new data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to update a `Fragment`/entire `FragmentManager`. I'm using the `FragmentManager` that comes with the SDK (sliding tabs) and inside one is a form for a login. When the login is finished (which I have figured out, it uses an `AsyncTask`) I'd like to reupdate the entire `FragmentManager` section. `FragmentTransaction`s have failed me (or at least I couldn't get them to work) so I'm wondering what's the best way to just refresh the UI.

Also, I have the custom menu with a logout button. When the user logs out, it should also refresh the UI (the tabs change based on whether or not the user is logged in).

**TL;DR** How do I refresh/reload an entire fragment system from inside and outside of the Fragments?

Also another thing that would be helpful, how do I make a Fragment update with new information (passing an array or a JSON array) after a different `AsyncTask` completes?

Comment: When you use your FragmentTransaction are you remembering to use `.commit()` afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to paste some of your code to see what is wrong with the FragmentManager.  Transactions should be completed after you call `<FragmentManager>.commit()`.

In regards to your second question:

To get your `Fragment` to update with new information, you should be able to just add a method like normal to your `Fragment` and call it.  If you are calling the method from the `AsyncTask` then just be careful with `Context`.  Take a look at this:

[How to call parent activity function from ASyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523438/how-to-call-parent-activity-function-from-asynctask)

Comment: I think I figured out what was going on with the Fragment not updating on commit(), I believe it was updating just not passing the information correctly (hence no *actual* visible update to the UI).

On the other hand, I still have no idea how to update the UI from part of Fragment because as far as I can tell, Fragment's

   `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater linf, ViewGroup cont,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

creates many problems, because it *returns* the `View`. How would I tell the UI to call this again to get the new `View`?

Comment: It depends what exactly you are doing.  Generally you can just update the data source and not have to completely recreate the `View`.  For instance, in one of my `Fragments` I have a `ListView` and when I pass data to it from my `Activity` I internally call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and the adapter updates for me.  You can also use `getView()` to get a reference to the `View` that the `Fragment` is using and then access any methods such as `setText()`.