# Can't access "findViewById" in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using an AsyncTask class to download data from a php file. After downloading, I want to put this data, into different TextViews, but I can't use the method findViewById.

The problem, is that I'm doing this by separate classes, and it all within a fragment.

This is my code:

```
public class RecuperarComentarisFoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
private Context mContext;
[...]
public RecuperarComentarisFoto(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    [...]
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { 
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", "1"));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_comentaris, "GET", params);
    JSONArray productObj;
    //HERE I RETRIEVE DATA FROM JSON. ITS WORKING OK.

    return null;
}
```

And where I've the problem:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    this.pDialog.dismiss();
    TextView comentariEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.commentsMostrar);
}
```

I've tried this:

```
        TextView comentariEditText = (TextView) mContext.findViewById(R.id.commentsMostrar);
```

But isn't working too.

Note that I'm calling this AsyncTask from a Fragment. As you can see, I had to pass the context retrieved by getActivity() to the AsyncTask:

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {
Context cont;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    cont=getActivity();
    new RecuperarComentarisFoto(cont).execute();
    return myFragmentView;
}


}
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pass your inflated view to the AsyncTask like this :

```
public class RecuperarComentarisFoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
private Context mContext;
private View rootView;
[...]
public RecuperarComentarisFoto(Context context, View rootView){
    this.mContext=context;
    this.rootView=rootView;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    [...]
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { 
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", "1"));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_comentaris, "GET", params);
    JSONArray productObj;
    //HERE I RETRIEVE DATA FROM JSON. ITS WORKING OK.

    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //super.onPostExecute(result);  <--GET RID OF THIS (it will screw up on 2.1 devices)
    this.pDialog.dismiss();
    // use rootview to findViewById
    TextView comentariEditText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.commentsMostrar);
}
```

Then call like so,

```
View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

cont=getActivity();
new RecuperarComentarisFoto(cont, myFragmentView).execute();
```

Comment: context usually refers to the Application or the activity being used.  Views are UI elements such as TextViews/buttons and containers (LinearLayout, etc.

Comment: @petey: Can't you just pass `Activity` and get `View` and `Context` from it?

Comment: You could also pass the activity

Answer (score 3):

Try this `((Activity)context)` it works for me...

```
TextView comentariEditText = 
(TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.commentsMostrar);
```

Comment: Best answer. Thank you!

Comment: Gives me this warning: "This field leaks a context object". Other than that it's working great, thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

## Make your AsyncTask independent of Activity

***What if***

- Your `AsyncTask` is a seperate Java class **(Outside of Activity)**
  and you still want to access the View elements of any `Activity` from
  `AsyncTask`.
- You want to reuse your `AsyncTask` with some other Activity without
  any code change in the your `AsyncTask`

***Answer is***. Use an interface

> **Advantage?**
>   An interface makes things independent (loosely coupled)

#### You can follow these steps:

**1) Create an interface**

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener{

   public void giveProgress(int progress);

}
```

**2) Use listener in your AsyncTask**

```
 DownloadSongTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>{

    private AsyncTaskListener listener;

    public DownloadSongTask(Context context)
    {
        listener= (AsyncTaskListener)context;    // Typecast 
    }

    @Override
    public void doInbackGround(String... params)
    {
         // Download code
         int downloadPerc = // calculate that
         publish(downloadPerc);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params)
    {
         listener.giveProgress(params[0]);  // Use it 
    }

}
```

**3) Implement the interface in the Activity and Override method**

```
 public class YourActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements AsyncTaskListener{

    private TextView textView;

    // Activity code //
    new  DownloadSongTask(this).execute("Paradise.mp3");  // this is how you start Task

    @Override 
    public void giveProgress(int progress){
       textView.setText(progress+"");      
    }

}
```

### Future

You will not realize the beauty of your code until you have to use Your AsyncTask in some other Activity.
Lets say in future you want to use this `AsyncTask` in some Other Activity which shows progress in a Spinner.
How will you use it ? 
**Simple! implement the interface and override the method.**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements AsyncTaskListener{

     private Spinner spinner;

     // Activity code //
     new  DownloadSongTask(this).execute("Paradise.mp3");  // this is how you start Task

    @Override 
    public void giveProgress(int progress){
       // Your Spinner code       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try as after passing `MyFragmentA` context instead of `getActivity()` :

```
 cont=this;
 new RecuperarComentarisFoto(cont).execute();
```

and change `RecuperarComentarisFoto` as

```
public class RecuperarComentarisFoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
public Fragment mContext;
[...]
public RecuperarComentarisFoto(Fragment context){
    this.mContext=context;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    this.pDialog.dismiss();
    TextView comentariEditText = 
                    (TextView)mContext.findViewById(R.id.commentsMostrar);
}
//...your code..
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a extra parameter to your AsyncTask with the view myFragmentView and find your textview on that.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    cont=getActivity();
    new RecuperarComentarisFoto(cont, myFragmentView).execute();
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

and then just use that view..

```
TextView comentariEditText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.commentsMostrar);
```

Comment: The provision of `mView` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `myFragmentView` global, this way you can access your views from anywhere even from your fragment methods like `onStart()`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer with use of `RecuperarComentarisFoto(Context context, View rootView)` gives me the message:

```
java\MyFragmentA.java:64: error: constructor RecuperarComentarisFoto in class RecuperarComentarisFoto cannot be applied to given types;
                new RecuperarComentarisFoto(cont, myFragmentView).execute();
                ^
  required: no arguments
  found: MyFragmentA,View
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I don't know why the result is different from the proposal above. I used API version 24.

Therefore I use an additional method `initialize()` inside the `AsyncTask`:

```
public class RecuperarComentarisFoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    ...
    public initialize(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }
    ...
}
```

And inside of the calling MyFragmentA class:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        cont=getActivity();

        RecuperarComentarisFoto rcf = new RecuperarComentarisFoto();
        rcf.initialize(cont, myFragmentViewt);
        rcf.execute(this);
        ...
    }
```