# findViewById() in asyncTask

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I want to use findViewById() method in AsyncTask class... i tried onPostExecute() and onPreExecute().but it doesnt work

```
class Proccess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult); // cause error
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult); // cause error
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult); // cause error

    }
}
```

Comment: why you want TextView in async task?

Comment: for changing text + i want to add more text view to RelativeLayout !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your code like this

```
class Proccess extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult); // cuse error
    return null; //this should be the last statement otherwise cause unreachable code.
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult); // cuse error
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult); // cuse error

}
}
```

And your **Process class should be innerclass** of Your Activity. **other wise it cause method findViewById(int) is undefined.**

Comment: That's what I am saying change your code like my updated code.

Comment: and copy paste your Process class inside your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably pass your view to the AsyncTask constructor, as mentionned in [Can't access "findViewById" in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164128/cant-access-findviewbyid-in-asynctask) , though I think only a weak reference should be kept, in case the view doesn't exist anymore when onPostExecute gets fired (so we don't use an obsolete view or prevent its garbage collection):

```java
public class Process extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    private WeakReference<TextView> textViewRef;

    public Process(TextView textView) {
        this.textViewRef = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // do your stuff in background
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView textView = textViewRef.get();
        if (textView != null) {
            // do something with it
        }
        else {
            // the view has been destroyed
        }
    }
}
```

Don't have time to check it right now, but that should do it, provided your activity / fragment passes the view to the asynctask.

Oh, and by the way: never use a view in any way in doInBackground as this method gets executed on a background thread, and UI components should only be manipulated from the main thread.

Comment: I don't have enough stack-overflow reputation to comment Tarun's post, but it's definitely wrong: 1/ the 'edited' code still contains a reference to the textview in doInBackground, which is *very** bad as it violates threading rules (see rule #2 in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads). 2/ I do agree with Snicolas that using findViewById directly in the async task is bad practice (esp. in case of screen rotation occurring during the async task).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the reference to your textview inside your activity and store as a data member. It would be accessible from an inner AsyncTask.

The drawback of using findViewById inside postExecute is that your AsyncTask may terminate after the death of your activity and findViewById would then crash your app.