# Error setting ListAdapter in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask

Here is my onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask Class

```
myNewsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
                CustomListAdapter customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(values, getApplicationContext());
                myNewsListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
```

And here is the CustomListAdapter Class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String Title[];
    Context ctxt;
    LayoutInflater myInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(String arr[], Context c)
    {
        Title = arr;
        ctxt = c;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return Title[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, viewGroup);
        TextView titleText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
        TextView descriptionText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.newsDescription);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);

        titleText.setText(Title[i]);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception every time I try to set the adapter on this line `myNewsListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);`.

Here is the logCat output.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at samarth.learning.http.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:674)
            at samarth.learning.http.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:374)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably `myNewsListView` is `null` make sure you are calling `setContentView` method with layout in which ListView present with `newsListView` id

Comment: All runs well if I comment out the line  `myNewsListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter); ` which means that the `setContentView()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `myNewsListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter)` your `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.newsListView)` is probably getting NULL.

You should execute `myNewsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newsListView)` outside of AsyncTask.
Further reading: [Can't access “findViewById” in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164128/cant-access-findviewbyid-in-asynctask)