# How to fix NullPointerException in Bufferedreader on Android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

**Goal:**
Reading a HTML-file using Buffered reader in an `AsyncTask` on Android.

**Problem:**
The debug log gives the following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`. It gives the error at the *onPostExecute* void. On further investigation I found out the following code: `TVCode.setText(result);` is throwing the `NullPointerException`. This means *result* = *null*. I can't find out why *result* = *null* since similar code on the normal Java, *using Eclipse*, is working fine.

**Further info:**

Android Studio: 1.3.2

JDK: 1.7.0_79-b15 amd64

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Gradle:
minSdkVersion 15,
targetSdkVersion 23, compileSdkVersion 23

Here is the code of *MainActivity.java*:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static String ETURL = null;
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();



    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView TVCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVCode);
        ImageButton BTSend = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.BTSend);
        final EditText ETURLInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETUrlInput);

        BTSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          ETURL = ETURLInput.getText().toString();

                                          new aSync().execute(ETURLInput.getText().toString());


                                      }


                                  }
        );

}

private class aSync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... ETURL)   {
        String line=null;
        String result="";


            try {
                URL url;

                url = new URL("" + ETURL);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();


                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                line=br.readLine();
                while (line!= null) {

                    result=result+line;
                    line=br.readLine();
                }

                br.close();

                return result;


            } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Error:", e);
            }


        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)  {
        try {
            TextView TVCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVCode);
            TVCode.setText(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fix:**

The `TextView` must be declared in the `onPreExecute` method instead of the on `onPostExecute` method. Thank you all for your help and time.

Comment: Please post the nullPointerException. Which line ?

Comment: And while you are at it ... please edit your question for proper indenting. You expect us to spend our time to help you; so you should spend some of your time to provide your input in a form that is immediately readable. Formatting matters; because without it people have to spend much more time to grasp the content of your question!

Comment: What is the value for `result`? Don't initialize textView again in `onPostExecute()` method. You have already initialized in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Comment the udation of textview in post execute and only print result check what is result.

Comment: @PiyushGupta The reason I'm declaring it again in _onPostExecute_ is because Android Studio gives the error: _Cannot resolve symbol TVCode_.

Comment: Here's the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference. The error is onPostExecute: TVCode.setText(result);. @Henry

Comment: @Jägermeister I'm sorry about the invonveinence and I updated the formatting. I appreciate you spend some of your time to help me. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the errorlog: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference. The error is onPostExecute: TVCode.setText(result);. @VVB

Comment: @Singhak Please be clearer. I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: I think I know where you might be wrong. Could you post your activity_main.xml file ? I believe either the view TVCode is missing, or there is a typo.

Comment: Comment the the line where you are updating textview in onpostexecute then only check value of result in log. If result is null then check in doInbackground your while loop is executing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the `onPostExecute()`. here you are trying to use `findViewById()`. But there is no view to be found. Hence the issue. You need to call the `findViewById()` on the activity or the inflated layout. If it's an activity, you need to pass the activity context to the async task and in case of fragment, you could pass in the inflated view.

More info here : [Can't access "findViewById" in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164128/cant-access-findviewbyid-in-asynctask)