# How to single instantiate view by calling findviewbyid method in non activity class?

Tags: android

In this code below can i only once instantiate view? Then, I can using it for some method in helper class.

```
public class Helper {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    public Helper(Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void firstMethod() {
        textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);

        textView.setText(R.string.some_text_1);
        button.setText("Tes1 Button")
    }

    public void secondMethod() {
        textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);

        textView.setText(R.string.some_text_2);
        button.setText("Tes2 Button")
    }
}
```

As you can see textView and button instantiate twice in different method, but I just want single instantiate. How to code that?

**UPDATE**

In activity we can do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //see this code
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```

And then in method we just do like this:

```
public void someMethod() {
        textView.setText(R.string.some_text_2);
        button.setText("Tes2 Button")
}
```

I need code like shown above in non activity. is it possible ?

Comment: Why don’t you want to call findViewById for your views once in your Helper constructor?

Comment: I want to simplify my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you can instantiate them in your constructor, like this

```
public Helper(Context context) {
    // You really don't even need to save context in this case since
    // you only use it in the constructor. If your real problem is more
    // complex you may still need to though
    this.context = context;

    textView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    button = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```

then you don't have to do so in `firstMethod` and `secondMethod`, which can just be

```
public void firstMethod() {
    textView.setText(R.string.some_text_1);
    button.setText("Tes1 Button")
}

public void secondMethod() {
    textView.setText(R.string.some_text_2);
    button.setText("Tes2 Button")
}
```

You could then create your helper class from within, say, your Activity `onCreate` like

```
private Helper helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_till);
    helper = new Helper(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you solved my problem. I have tried put them in my constructor  before but my app crash, because I init helper class in outside of onCreate, this cause the app crash.

Comment: You're welcome. You can't call findViewById before you've called  setContentView, which is probably why it didn't work for you before.

Answer (score 0):

Use context instead of activity:-

Make sure you need to pass Activity to Non Activity class as constructor parameter as you are initialized in your code.

refer:-[findViewById in non activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055627/findviewbyid-in-non-activity-class/42055839#42055839)

```
   public void secondMethod() {
        textView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        button = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.button);

        textView.setText(R.string.some_text_2);
        button.setText("Tes2 Button")
    }
```

Comment: i have pass activity to non-activity. can you see my question again pls. i update it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make initialization in constructor:

```
public Helper(Context context, Activity activity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;

    textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```